# Einstein Language - Intent

Tags: einstein

Does anybody know what type of algorithm is used by einstein intent API ?
https://metamind.readme.io/docs/intro-to-einstein-language

is this some sort of classification algorithm ?

Also, how does this compare against PredictionIO on heroku which has its own algorithms for classification, recommendation etc.

Any insight would be very helpful

Comment: @MohithShrivastava perhaps you can answer this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explanation from the Salesforce blog of the Algorithms Powering Einstein Vision and Einstein Language

> As we've learned in previous blogs, deep learning based neural networks are used for text classification and image classification. The topology of neural networks can differ, for example, text classification labels can be intent based or sentiment based.
>
> Einstein Platform Services use supervised learning techniques to train models on labeled training data. The training dataset consists of labeled images or labeled text documents and is uploaded to Einstein Platform Services via an API call. Next, a REST API call is made to train the dataset and the output is a trained model with a unique model ID. Predicting classifiers for new images that the model has never seen before is also executed through an API call.

Here is the relationship from a product standpoint:

[image: MetaMind and PredictionIO]

**References**

- [Using Einstein APIs Within Python | Developer Force Blog](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2017/10/using-einstein-apis-within-python.html)
- [Salesforce research: Learning when to skim and when to read](https://einstein.ai/research/learning-when-to-skim-and-when-to-read)
- [Inside Salesforce Einstein Artificial Intelligence (pdf)](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/reports/inside-einstein.pdf)